# Retrieve cronjob_code or other params like schedule info of a cron job inside a cron function?

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

If `cron_job()` is my function running the cron job

```
function cron_job(){
     // I would like to get the current job_id or the cron schedule model here
}
```

Is there any way to retrieve this data in Magento version > 1.9

Comment: Please be a bit more clear with your question. Providing an actual function example and an explanation of what you hope to achieve would help.

Comment: @MagenX how is this a duplicate? It doesn't mention the scheduler anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cronjob methods can take a `Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule` parameter which contains the job metadata (you can even change it).

### Example:

```
function cron_job(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule $schedule)
{
    $id = $schedule->getId(); // ID in `cron_schedule` database table
    $jobCode = $schedule->getJobCode();
    $status = $schedule->getStatus(); // will be "running" obviously
    $messages = $schedule->getMessages();
    $createdAt = $schedule->getCreatedAt();
    $scheduledAt = $schedule->getScheduledAt();
    $executedAt = $schedule->getExecutedAt(); 
    $finishedAt = $schedule->getFinishedAt(); // will be empty since the job is not finished yet
}
```